# What is wrong with my Java coding? It is saying that it cannot find the symbol scanf. How should I recode this?

Tags: java, scanf

I am trying to make a Java code that enables the user to input any number and the Java makes a triangle out of that number using `*`

My code is not compiling, but I think I've finally almost got it down.  The only problem is, that it is not recognizing **scanf**.

***Here is my code:***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class triangle
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      char print='*';
      int row,col;
      int noOfRows;
      System.out.printf("Enter number of rows to be printed\n");
      scanf("%d",noOfRows);
      {
         for(col=1;col<=row;col++)
         { // this brace is useless, since there is only one statement in this                   for loop
            System.out.printf("%c",print);
         } // same for this one
         System.out.printf("\n");
      }
   }
}
```

***How can I fix this?***

Comment: The compiler can't find it because it doesn't exist...

Comment: Also this line ``System.out.`enter code here`printf("\n");`` is not going to work

Comment: Joshua, that would be a dream come true. All languages using the same syntax.

Comment: Haha  i'm new to this.  This is all so much to take in.  How would I recode this to work?

Comment: Start with [Scanning and formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanfor.html)

Answer (score 2):

scanf() and printf() are supported by C and C++ in java:
1. BufferedReader or Scanner for reading from console(System.in).
2. print() or println() for printing to console.(System.out).

Comment: You just spoke chinese to me.  haha  I have no idea what i'm doing.  =/  Its sad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a new object of the scanner.
Also, to print, is `System.out.println("");`

Comment: How do I declare a new object of the scanner?  And how do I know which object to declare?

Comment: `Scanner nameofscanner = new Scanner(System.in);` Then when you read the variable, you should put `nameofavriable = nameofscanner.next();` You should specify the type of variable between .next and (); like `.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

You should use Scanner class like this: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` and do something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter number of rows");

noOfRows = scanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score -1):

My friend, you use `scanf` in `"C"`of `"C++"` in java we use `System.in`

Comment: Just using System.in won't work. It needs to be decorated by another InputStream.

Comment: So how would you recode it?  I'm just so confused on how to go about it.